Can I make a .env variable composed of two other .env variables with the dotenv note package?
I am working on a project where I need to join two .env variables to create a third one. The reason as to why I don't just make the first one the way I need it is because I would have to manually update the credentials in every heroku app whenever the credentials are rotated. While on the other apps it's not an issue as I can just call:
db_uri=`${process.env.db_url}?schema=${process.env.db_schema};`

There is one app where this solution brings about multiple bugs due to Prisma ORM limitations.
I want to know if there is some type of syntax that can be used for the heroku platform and for the dotenv node package to do something like this:
.env
db_url = my_db_url
db_schema = my_schema
db_url_w_schema = $db_url?schema=$db_schema



Have you considered https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-expand ? You may find a solution with that package.

Yea, we used that in the end. Thank you
